# Can't get attribute values or get Error XQDY0025 in XQuery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, exist-db, exide

I get nothing or "Error XQDY0025" when I use the XQuery below. However, eXide shows "Found 4 in 0.004s", please help me, I can't find the problem.

```
for $s in doc("customers.xml")/customers/Customer 
return $s/@Name
```

to query the`Name` attributes from the XML document below:

```
<customers>
    <Customer Name="c2">
        <Order OrderNumber="o1">
            <Item Description="ab">i1</Item>
        </Order>
    </Customer>
    <Customer Name="c3">
        <Order OrderNumber="o2">
            <Item Description="cd">i2</Item>
            <Item Description="ef">i3</Item>
        </Order>
        <Order OrderNumber="o2">
            <Item Description="cfg">i5</Item>
        </Order>
    </Customer>
    <Customer Name="c1">
        <Order OrderNumber="o1">
            <Item Description="abc">i1</Item>
            <Item Description="def">i2</Item>
        </Order>
    </Customer>
    <Customer Name="c4">
        <Order OrderNumber="o1">
            <Item Description="abc">i1</Item>
        </Order>
        <Order OrderNumber="o2">
            <Item Description="def">i2</Item>
        </Order>
    </Customer>
</customers>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error code `XQDY0025` ([XQuery 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#ERRXQDY0025), [XQuery 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#ERRXQDY0025)) means you've tried to add two attributes with the same name to the same element.

There's nothing wrong with the XPath expression as such - it returns a sequence of attribute nodes, but since all those nodes have the same name you can't add more than one of them to the same element in the output.

Comment: Perhaps wrapping `$s/@Name` in a data function would help @alex. e.g. `data($s/@Name)`?